# Green screen with X org / Black screen with Gnome RD on Wayland

Tags: gnome, 22.04, xorg, remote-desktop, wayland

So this is probably 2 issues but they are related so I need to put them in the same thread.

My goal is to use Gnome Remote Desktop and establishing the connection is fine. Except, when using Wayland as the DE the screen is just black, mouse and keyboard seem to work but I can't see anything.

As a step to resolve this I thought I would try the same with X org. And yes, this did resolve the Remote desktop issue which displays perfectly. However the local display is flourescent green.

So my questions:

Should Gnome Remote Desktop work with Wayland? If so, any thoughts on where the problem may lie? (I tried installing pipewire as I've seen mentioned in another post but no luck)

What could cause the green screen under X org. (I think it uses nvidia if that's relevant)

Ubuntu 22.04 and Remmina 1.4.33 as the RDP client